# Determine the location (memory address) where the driver module is residing

Tags: c, linux, kernel, driver, memory-address

When a linux kernel driver is loaded dynamically, how do we write a C function to report the location (memory address) where the driver module is residing?

This is more for windows, however, if we adapt similar for Linux driver will that work?

```
    long sizeOfExe = 0;   
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("./Mini.ko", "rb"); // reading itself

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    sizeOfExe = ftell(fp);

    printf("The size of this driver module is: %ld bytes\n", sizeOfExe);   
    int* addressStartOfFile = &fp;
    printf("Location of this driver module starts at: 0x%x\n", addressStartOfFile);        
    printf("Location of this driver module ends at: 0x%x\n", (addressStartOfFile+sizeOfExe));

/*
The size of this driver module is: 18727 bytes
Location of this driver module starts at: 0x28ff30
Location of this driver module ends at: 0x2a23cc
*/
```

Comment: It would be relatively easy for parts of the driver to obtain the address of the functions which comprise it, just as in other C code.  By why would you want this information?

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, could you give a sample C function to do that? The reason is because there is a requirement to do a error detection code on-the-fly.

Comment: The `&` operator works on function names, too.   Beware of things like instruction and data caches though!  The view of memory you get in one mode may not be the same as that in the other, if there have been any recent changes (/memory errors?).

Comment: I do share your views, and that is what I am concerned with. As I am not very well-versed in Linux kernels, I am concerned with access and virtual memory issues (and other concerns such as the memory mapping issues as well). Is there a way to ascertain this?

Thank you, @ChrisStratton.

Comment: No, that code sample shouldn't be expected to work.  I'd be a bit surprised if it even worked on Windows.  There are two major problems: you assume that data and code spaces are contiguous in that order, and you assume that there is a "file" remotely resembles the in-memory footprint.  I'd be much more inclined to take the address of the first and last functions and also of the first and last data elements - and I'd not expect the two to (necessarily) be contiguous.  But if you try to walk the memory to verify it, beware that data access to code memory may go through a different cache.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, could you give a sample C function to demonstrate what you just said?

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, how may we account for the issues (contiguous memory, MMU, etc) you mentioned?

Comment: If this is for an integrity self-check, you can't do it that way. Loading the module performs some linking, which changes the code.

Comment: sharp observation, @Gilles. 
+1 for you. 

I can't use the answer to remove that requirement unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

> When a linux kernel driver is loaded dynamically, how do we write a C
>   function to report the location (memory address) where the driver
>   module is residing?

We write it to read (via `popen()` etc.) the output of, or translate into C, the shell command

```
grep '\[modulename]' /proc/k*syms | sort
```